# Call js function after html page loaded in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating jQuerymobile website. I have a tag like this in `page1.html`

```
  <a href="Page2.html">go to page 2</a>
```

If I click on it will go Page2.html. After the page is loaded I need to call a js function .
I tried 2 ways to put the function

1. At the body tag `onload="ExampleFunction()"` at Page2.html
2. `<script>window.onload=ExampleFunction</script>` inside the body

but both are not working.

Comment: Set up your whole code on jsfiddle.net please. What you said here doesn't make much sense.

Comment: its gives any error ? you can open in chrome and check in developer tools to rule out some common mistakes. and add some more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using jQuery Mobile, you **don't** use `onload` or `ready`, you use [`pageinit`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html):

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: i should put this function at where?

Comment: @user983738: Anywhere you like after including jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @user983738: The jQuery Mobile site (linked above) is littered with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery (this will bypass any browser specific page load functionality).

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Additionally if you would like to call a JavaScript function only when directed to the 2nd page from the 1st page... you can include a query string within the page URL.

```
<a href="Page2.html?callmyfunc=true">go to page 2</a>
```

And upon page load check the parameters of the URL, and eventually trigger a function call.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I didn't see the jQuery mobile part :)